# How to secure my web api in mvc 4

Tags: c#, android, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

http://localhost:1075/api/customer/Getcustomer?id=1

1.Above url get me result of perticular user profile information.. following is controller code.This web api called and designed  for android application.but even if I called it from my browser or postman tool it gives me result. then where is security?? If anyone knows this url then he can access all our sesitive information. Please suggest me how can secure my web api...

```
 public customerCollection Getcustomer(int id)
        {          
            db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            var customer = (from c in db.customers
                                 where c.customerID == id
                                 select c).ToArray();
            var result = new customerCollection();
            if (customer == null)
            {
                result.status = "failed";
            }
            result.status = "success";
            result.customerArray = customer;
            return result;
        }
```

And response is

```
{
  "customerArray": [
    {
      "customerID": 1,
      "cname": "Yogesh",
      "cmobile": "9970714878",
      "cemail": "yogeshkhurpe11@gmail.com",
      "cpassword": "yogesh",
      "addressLine1": "balaji hostel",
      "addressLine2": "Jadhav nagar",
      "area": "Vadgoan",
      "pincode": "411041",
      "cimage": "Na",
      "cdate": "2017-06-28T14:16:03",
      "cstatus": "active",
      "orders": []
    }
  ],
  "status": "success"
}
```

Comment: You should also consider doing it a post request along with some authentication, like an auth token which changes every time you login with some credentials, and old token expires, And consider doing this in a SSL tunnel, so it would be secure. :)

Comment: And your Api should fail if the request is sent without the auth token.

Comment: You can uses the ASP.Net identity and owin, So as to you can authenticates as a token based. Its provide the security

Answer (score 0):

Here is the step by step way to use authentication.

You should create an Authorize attribute in you WebAPI to Authorize an incoming request first.

First of all the user who is going to use your API will authenticate himself using username and password, once this process gets completed and user has been authorized you should return a token to the user for further requests. This token can be the encrypted time or GUID or anything whatever you prefer to know about the particular user, that for whom you have generated that token. You can save that token into the database for further uses.

Now next time when user will try to access your API, he will send the token in the header section of that api request. If the token is valid you should return the results else you should return an error stating that token is invalid.

Thanks
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following logic.
First  create an Authorize attribute in you WebAPI.
Use the Authorize attribute above your api function to protect the api's

```
public class AuthenticationFilter : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// read requested header and validated
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="actionContext"></param>
            public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
            {
                var identity = FetchFromHeader(actionContext);

                if(identity != null)
                {
                    //get the user based on the identity
                    var user=TokenService.getUserFromToken(identity);
                    if (user)
                    {
                        CurrentThread.SetPrincipal(new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(user), null), null, null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                    return;
                }
                base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// retrive header detail from the request 
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="actionContext"></param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            private string FetchFromHeader(HttpActionContext actionContext)
            {
                string requestToken = null;

                var authRequest = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization;
                if (authRequest != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(authRequest.Scheme) && authRequest.Scheme == "Basic")
                    requestToken = authRequest.Parameter;

                return requestToken;
            }
        }
```